Python - Get sum of all sizes of packages installed
How to get the total sum of sizes of all packages in a Python requirements.txt file? Or a pip freeze.
I want to figure out how much space all packages take up. I know this exists but it doesn't show how to get the sum.

Slightly adapting @Tirtha answer from the link you provided, here is a version also displaying the total size of all packages:
import os
import pkg_resources

def calc_container(path):
    total_size = 0
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for f in filenames:
            fp = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
            total_size += os.path.getsize(fp)
    return total_size

dists = [d for d in pkg_resources.working_set]

total_size = 0
for dist in dists:
    try:
        path = os.path.join(dist.location, dist.project_name)
        size = calc_container(path)
        if size/1000 > 1.0:
            print (f"{dist}: {size/1000} KB")
            print("-"*40)
            total_size += size/1000
    except OSError:
        "{} no longer exists".format(dist.project_name)

print("="*40)
print(f"Total size of all packages: {round(total_size, 2)} KB")


I had already created a python file for me long back. i.e before seeing your question. Running it after a long time after seeing your  question.
Install pipreqs module if not installed
pip3 install pipreqs

installed_packages.py
import subprocess as sp
import re

def get_installed():
    # Get the list of installed packages
    op = sp.check_output(['pip', 'freeze']).decode('utf-8')
    ls = [line.split('==')[0] for line in op.splitlines()]
    return ls

def get_size(package):
    # Get package details
    try:
        op = sp.check_output(['pip', 'show', package]).decode('utf-8')
    except sp.CalledProcessError:
        return 0
    
    # Find the location of the package
    location_match = re.search(r'^Location: (.*)', op, re.MULTILINE)
    if location_match:
        location = location_match.group(1)
        
        # Get the size of the directory
        try:
            size_op = sp.check_output(['du', '-sb', location]).decode('utf-8')
            size = int(size_op.split()[0])
            return size
        except Exception as e:
            return 0
    return 0

def main():
    packages = get_installed()
    total = 0

    for x in packages:
        size = get_size(x)
        total = total + size
        print(f'{x}: {size / (1024 * 1024):.2f} MB')
    
    print(f'\nTotal size of all packages: {total / (1024 * 1024):.2f} MB')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

My Output:
annotated-types: 1018.58 MB
anyio: 1018.58 MB
apturl: 169.51 MB
argcomplete: 169.51 MB
argon2-cffi: 1018.58 MB
argon2-cffi-bindings: 1018.58 MB
arrow: 1018.58 MB
asttokens: 1018.58 MB
async-lru: 1018.58 MB
attrs: 1018.58 MB
avg: 1018.58 MB
Babel: 1018.58 MB
bcrypt: 169.51 MB
beautifulsoup4: 1018.58 MB
bleach: 1018.58 MB
blinker: 1018.58 MB
blis: 1018.58 MB
bottle: 1018.58 MB
Brlapi: 169.51 MB
bubblemail: 169.51 MB
catalogue: 1018.58 MB
certifi: 1018.58 MB
cffi: 1018.58 MB
chardet: 169.51 MB
charset-normalizer: 1018.58 MB
chrome-gnome-shell: 169.51 MB
click: 1018.58 MB
cloudpathlib: 1018.58 MB
colorama: 169.51 MB
comm: 1018.58 MB
command-not-found: 169.51 MB
confection: 1018.58 MB
contourpy: 1018.58 MB
cryptography: 169.51 MB
cupshelpers: 169.51 MB
customtkinter: 1018.58 MB
cycler: 1018.58 MB
cymem: 1018.58 MB
darkdetect: 1018.58 MB
dateparser: 1018.58 MB
dbus-python: 169.51 MB
debugpy: 1018.58 MB
decorator: 1018.58 MB
deepdiff: 1018.58 MB
defer: 169.51 MB
defusedxml: 1018.58 MB
distlib: 169.51 MB
distro: 169.51 MB
distro-info: 169.51 MB
dnspython: 169.51 MB
docopt: 1018.58 MB
duplicity: 169.51 MB
WARNING: Package(s) not found: en-core-web-sm @ https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-3.7.1/en_core_web_sm-3.7.1-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=86cc141f63942d4b2c5fcee06630fd6f904788d2f0ab005cce45aadb8fb73889
en-core-web-sm @ https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-3.7.1/en_core_web_sm-3.7.1-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=86cc141f63942d4b2c5fcee06630fd6f904788d2f0ab005cce45aadb8fb73889: 0.00 MB
evdev: 1018.58 MB
example: 1018.58 MB
exceptiongroup: 1018.58 MB
executing: 1018.58 MB
fasteners: 169.51 MB
fastjsonschema: 1018.58 MB
filelock: 169.51 MB
Flask: 1018.58 MB
Flask-Cors: 1018.58 MB
Flask-Login: 1018.58 MB
Flask-MySQL: 1018.58 MB
flask-mysql-connector: 1018.58 MB
Flask-MySQLdb: 1018.58 MB
Flask-Reuploaded: 1018.58 MB
Flask-SQLAlchemy: 1018.58 MB
Flask-Uploads: 1018.58 MB
fonttools: 1018.58 MB
fpdf: 1018.58 MB
fqdn: 1018.58 MB
future: 169.51 MB
greenlet: 1018.58 MB
h11: 1018.58 MB
html5lib: 169.51 MB
httpcore: 1018.58 MB
httplib2: 169.51 MB
httpx: 1018.58 MB
idna: 169.51 MB
imageio: 1018.58 MB
imageio-ffmpeg: 1018.58 MB
importlib-metadata: 169.51 MB
install: 1018.58 MB
ipykernel: 1018.58 MB
ipython: 1018.58 MB
ipython_genutils: 169.51 MB
isoduration: 1018.58 MB
itsdangerous: 1018.58 MB
jedi: 1018.58 MB
jeepney: 169.51 MB
Jinja2: 1018.58 MB
jmespath: 1018.58 MB
joblib: 1018.58 MB
json5: 1018.58 MB
jsonpointer: 1018.58 MB
jsonschema: 1018.58 MB
jsonschema-specifications: 1018.58 MB
jupyter-events: 1018.58 MB
jupyter-lsp: 1018.58 MB
jupyter_client: 1018.58 MB
jupyter_core: 1018.58 MB
jupyter_server: 1018.58 MB
jupyter_server_terminals: 1018.58 MB
jupyterlab_pygments: 1018.58 MB
jupyterlab_server: 1018.58 MB
keyboard: 1018.58 MB
keyring: 169.51 MB
kiwisolver: 1018.58 MB
langcodes: 1018.58 MB
language-selector: 169.51 MB
launchpadlib: 169.51 MB
lazr.restfulclient: 169.51 MB
lazr.uri: 169.51 MB
lml: 1018.58 MB
lockfile: 169.51 MB
louis: 169.51 MB
lxml: 169.51 MB
macaroonbakery: 169.51 MB
Mako: 169.51 MB
MarkupSafe: 1018.58 MB
matplotlib: 1018.58 MB
matplotlib-inline: 1018.58 MB
mistune: 1018.58 MB
monotonic: 169.51 MB
more-itertools: 169.51 MB
MouseInfo: 1018.58 MB
murmurhash: 1018.58 MB
mysql-connector-python: 1018.58 MB
mysqlclient: 1018.58 MB
natsort: 169.51 MB
nbclient: 1018.58 MB
nbconvert: 1018.58 MB
nbformat: 1018.58 MB
nest-asyncio: 1018.58 MB
netifaces: 169.51 MB
nltk: 1018.58 MB
notebook_shim: 1018.58 MB
num2words: 1018.58 MB
numpy: 1018.58 MB
oauthlib: 169.51 MB
olefile: 169.51 MB
openai: 1018.58 MB
opencv-python: 1018.58 MB
ordered-set: 1018.58 MB
outcome: 1018.58 MB
overrides: 1018.58 MB
packaging: 1018.58 MB
pandas: 1018.58 MB
pandocfilters: 1018.58 MB
paramiko: 169.51 MB
parsedatetime: 1018.58 MB
parso: 1018.58 MB
passlib: 1018.58 MB
pathlib: 1018.58 MB
pexpect: 169.51 MB
Pillow: 1018.58 MB
platformdirs: 1018.58 MB
plum-dispatch: 1018.58 MB
polars: 1018.58 MB
preshed: 1018.58 MB
prometheus-client: 1018.58 MB
prompt-toolkit: 1018.58 MB
protobuf: 169.51 MB
proxy-tools: 1018.58 MB
psutil: 1018.58 MB
ptyprocess: 169.51 MB
pure-eval: 1018.58 MB
PyAutoGUI: 1018.58 MB
pycairo: 169.51 MB
pycparser: 1018.58 MB
pycups: 169.51 MB
pydantic: 1018.58 MB
pydantic_core: 1018.58 MB
pyexcel: 1018.58 MB
pyexcel-io: 1018.58 MB
PyGetWindow: 1018.58 MB
Pygments: 1018.58 MB
PyGObject: 169.51 MB
PyJWT: 169.51 MB
pymacaroons: 169.51 MB
PyMsgBox: 1018.58 MB
PyMySQL: 1018.58 MB
PyNaCl: 169.51 MB
pynput: 1018.58 MB
pyparsing: 169.51 MB
pyperclip: 1018.58 MB
PyRect: 1018.58 MB
pyRFC3339: 169.51 MB
PyScreeze: 1018.58 MB
PySocks: 1018.58 MB
python-apt: 169.51 MB
python-dateutil: 1018.58 MB
python-debian: 169.51 MB
python-docx: 1018.58 MB
python-dotenv: 1018.58 MB
python-json-logger: 1018.58 MB
python-pptx: 1018.58 MB
python-vlc: 1018.58 MB
python-xlib: 1018.58 MB
python3-xlib: 1018.58 MB
pythonping: 1018.58 MB
pytweening: 1018.58 MB
pytz: 169.51 MB
pywebview: 1018.58 MB
pyxdg: 169.51 MB
PyYAML: 169.51 MB
pyzmq: 1018.58 MB
referencing: 1018.58 MB
regex: 1018.58 MB
requests: 1018.58 MB
rfc3339-validator: 1018.58 MB
rfc3986-validator: 1018.58 MB
rpds-py: 1018.58 MB
sdkmanager: 169.51 MB
SecretStorage: 169.51 MB
selenium: 1018.58 MB
Send2Trash: 1018.58 MB
six: 169.51 MB
smart-open: 1018.58 MB
sniffio: 1018.58 MB
sortedcontainers: 1018.58 MB
soupsieve: 1018.58 MB
spacy: 1018.58 MB
spacy-legacy: 1018.58 MB
spacy-loggers: 1018.58 MB
WARNING: Package(s) not found: Spire.Doc @ file:///home/muthu/Downloads/Spire.Doc-12.1.0-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=07235c8d63b315d0edbfeb23abd3a00176a1dbb874250e8e92ea1a3d2c90144c
Spire.Doc @ file:///home/muthu/Downloads/Spire.Doc-12.1.0-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#sha256=07235c8d63b315d0edbfeb23abd3a00176a1dbb874250e8e92ea1a3d2c90144c: 0.00 MB
SQLAlchemy: 1018.58 MB
srsly: 1018.58 MB
stack-data: 1018.58 MB
systemd-python: 169.51 MB
terminado: 1018.58 MB
texttable: 1018.58 MB
thinc: 1018.58 MB
tinycss2: 1018.58 MB
tkhtmlview: 1018.58 MB
tkinter-tooltip: 1018.58 MB
tkVideo: 1018.58 MB
tomli: 1018.58 MB
tornado: 1018.58 MB
tqdm: 1018.58 MB
traitlets: 1018.58 MB
trio: 1018.58 MB
trio-websocket: 1018.58 MB
ttkbootstrap: 1018.58 MB
typer: 1018.58 MB
types-python-dateutil: 1018.58 MB
typing_extensions: 1018.58 MB
tzdata: 1018.58 MB
tzlocal: 1018.58 MB
ubuntu-drivers-common: 169.51 MB
ubuntu-pro-client: 169.51 MB
ufw: 169.51 MB
unattended-upgrades: 169.51 MB
unicodeit: 1018.58 MB
uri-template: 1018.58 MB
urllib3: 169.51 MB
usb-creator: 169.51 MB
vboxapi: 169.51 MB
virtualenv: 169.51 MB
wadllib: 169.51 MB
wasabi: 1018.58 MB
wcwidth: 1018.58 MB
weasel: 1018.58 MB
webcolors: 1018.58 MB
webdriver-manager: 1018.58 MB
webencodings: 1018.58 MB
websocket-client: 1018.58 MB
Werkzeug: 1018.58 MB
wsproto: 1018.58 MB
wxPython: 169.51 MB
xdg: 169.51 MB
xkit: 169.51 MB
XlsxWriter: 1018.58 MB
zipp: 169.51 MB

Total size of all packages: 212694.09 MB


Interesting, why are there so many dependencies with the same size? Also, when I ran your script, it reported total size: 23143.89 MB, while du ....../site-packages/ reported 408MB. Why is there this discrepancy?

For my run, every package had 361.62 MB reported.

yes, The script calculates the size of entire directories. If a package installs a small file or a small set of files into a large directory (e.g., containing many dependencies or shared files), the script will report the size of the entire directory rather than just the size of the package's files. (Even my total size is 213GB)

The command:
$ pip freeze | \
 sed 's/==.*$//' | \
 tr '\n' ' ' | \
 xargs pip show | \
 grep 'Location:' | \
 awk '{print($2)}' | \
 tr '\n' ' ' | \
 xargs du -csh

My output:
365M    /home/stas/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
941M    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages
255M    /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
1,6G    total


That's an unholy mess of useless grep and related antipatterns.
